# NoClassDefFoundError on using log4j logger

Tags: java, android, logging, log4j

I am using log4j to store logs in files in my android device.

Following are my dependencies:

```
compile 'de.mindpipe.android:android-logging-log4j:1.0.3'
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```

Following is my `getLogger` method:

```
public static Logger getLogger(Class clazz, String logType) {
    String logsFolderName;
    logsFolderName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + PlayerProperties.logsFolder + File.separator;

    String logFilePrefix = PlayerProperties.androidId ;
    String logFileName = logFilePrefix + "_" + getCurrentDateString() + ".log";

    if (!(new File(logsFolderName).exists())) {
        new File(logsFolderName).mkdirs();
    }

    String absoluteFileName = new File(logsFolderName, logFileName).getAbsolutePath();
    logConfigurator.setFileName(absoluteFileName);
    logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.INFO);
    logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.INFO);
    logConfigurator.setUseFileAppender(true);
    logConfigurator.setFilePattern("%d %-5p [%c{2}]-[%L] %m%n");
    logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 3); // each log file max size - 3 MB
    logConfigurator.setImmediateFlush(true);
    logConfigurator.configure();
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(clazz);
    return log;
}
```

Usage:

```
public static Logger LOGGER = ALogger.getLogger(StorageTools.class);
```

While this works totally well in all android devices used till date, one particular android device (Version 4.4.2) throws the following exception:

```
04-29 08:10:02.982 3880-3880/com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer, PID: 3880
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at de.mindpipe.android.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator.setLevel(LogConfigurator.java:118)
        at com.blynq.app.tools.ALogger.getLogger(ALogger.java:49)
        at com.blynq.app.tools.ALogger.getLogger(ALogger.java:28)
        at com.blynq.app.tools.StorageTools.<clinit>(StorageTools.java:37)
        at com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer.MainPlayer.setPlayerDefaultConfiguration(MainPlayer.java:162)
        at com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer.MainPlayer.initiatePlayer(MainPlayer.java:99)
        at com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer.MainPlayer.onResume(MainPlayer.java:91)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1206)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5473)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone help me understand the issue?

Comment: Hi @Jay, If I may ask, why you using log4j logger in Android rather than Android Log?

Comment: Do you have a `(conflict resolution)` label for log4j dependency after running `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency log4j`?

Comment: Why do you have an example of usage `getLogger()` method with the only one argument?